# How do you see the stage of the second meiotic arrest in oogenesis in the given video?

Tags: meiosis, oogenesis

[My old question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/875/what-is-the-stage-of-meiosis-of-first-meiotic-arrest-of-oogenesis/901?iemail=1#901) raised this new question. After reading this [page](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10008/) I can say now that metaphase is the stage in which the second meiotic arrest occurs within oogenesis:

> The oocyte is arrested again in the metaphase of the second meiotic
>   division.

It is difficult to visualize the thing in my head. I could not find a video of specifically for oogenesis but probably the general model for meiosis holds true. The problem I am having is that I cannot see the arresting steps in this general [meiosis video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1_-mQS_FZ0).

**How do you see the second meiotic arrest of oogenesis in the above video?**

I cannot even see clearly the first meiotic arrest. I only know that it is in prophase for the first and metaphase for the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to understand the thing now.

The video is **utterly simplified for animal cell** meiosis I and II. 
In oogenesis, you get after every anaphase one cell with very little cytoplasm, polar body, and another cell with much cytoplasm. In the video, the amount of cytoplasm is equal so the thing is idealized.

The video is better to explain male gametogenesis: spermatogenesis, since the amount of cytoplasm does not differ after each anaphase.

The video is too going too fast to teach you oogenesis, since in reality the things are arrested rather long time. The second meiotic arrest in oogenesis can lasts 12 - 50 years starting after puberty. The rupturing secondary oocytes lasts then again less in the second meiotic arrest of oogenesis, since they start to develop into ovum after the monthly release.